# JSP: Using a delegate for 'out' ( jspWriter) with jsp includes to change the behaviour of Expressions

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Say, there is a class `MyJSPWriter` which extends `JspWriter` and implemented all the abstract methods.. And `print(String )` is modified to add some special behavior, so that all the expression that are strings would be treated differently ( May be I could use this for some special encoding or something like that-- this is a simplified example):

```
package com.myproject.base;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;

public class MyJSPWriter extends JspWriter{

    JspWriter out = null;

    public MyJSPWriter(JspWriter out) {
        super(0, true);
        this.out = out;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return out.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() throws IOException {
        out.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void clearBuffer() throws IOException {
        out.clearBuffer();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        out.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRemaining() {
        return out.getRemaining();
    }

    @Override
    public void newLine() throws IOException {
        out.newLine();
    }

    @Override
    public void print(boolean b) throws IOException {
        out.print(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(char c) throws IOException {
        out.print(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(int i) throws IOException {
        out.print(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(long l) throws IOException {
        out.print(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(float f) throws IOException {
        out.print(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(double d) throws IOException {
        out.print(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(char[] s) throws IOException {
        out.print(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String s) throws IOException {
        out.print("Processed String: " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(Object obj) throws IOException {
        out.print(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void println() throws IOException {
        out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public void println(boolean x) throws IOException {
        out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(char x) throws IOException {
        out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(int x) throws IOException {
        out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(long x) throws IOException {
        out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(float x) throws IOException {
        out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(double x) throws IOException {
        out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(char[] x) throws IOException {
           out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(String x) throws IOException {
           out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(Object x) throws IOException {
           out.println(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out.write(cbuf, off, len);
    }


}
```

And I have jsp ( say `Main.jsp`) which looks something like this:

```
<%@page import="com.myproject.base"%>
<% out = new MyJSPWriter(out); %>

<%= " Hello World" %>
```

So, in my output, it will appear like

```
Processed String: Hello World
```

Now, if i have some more jsp:includes, and may more inlcudes in each one of them..
eg:

Main.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.myproject.base"%>
<% out = new MyJSPWriter(out); %>

<%= " Hello World" %>
<jsp:include page="Sub1.jsp"></jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="Sub2.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Sub1.jsp

```
<%= " Hello World from sub1.jsp" %>
```

Sub2.jsp

```
<%= " Hello World from sub2.jsp" %>
<jsp:include page="Sub3.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

and so on...

But all the sub jsp's will have `out` objects of their own... :-(

**How can we bring the same behaviour to all included jsps without adding**

```
<% out = new MyJSPWriter(out); %>
```

**in each one of these files ( because i'm trying to use this in a legacy application) ?**

Is there any other way i can approach this?

**Additional Information:**
When we look at the generated .java file of the jsp, 
this is how part of the code look like

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    PageContext pageContext = null;
    HttpSession session = null;
    ServletContext application = null;
    ServletConfig config = null;
    JspWriter out = null;
    Object page = this;
    JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
    PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;


    try {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      pageContext = _jspxFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response,
                null, true, 8192, true);
      _jspx_page_context = pageContext;
      application = pageContext.getServletContext();
      config = pageContext.getServletConfig();
      session = pageContext.getSession();
      out = pageContext.getOut();
      _jspx_out = out;
      out = new MyJSPWriter(out);
      // and so on writing content ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the top of generated jsp class, you will see the following line

```
 private static final JspFactory _jspxFactory = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();
```

Now, one possible solution to customize `out` object is to have a custom `JspFactory` implmentation.

**Steps**

Create a custom JspFactory implementation

```
public class MyJspFactory extends JspFactory {
    private static JspFactory _myFactory = null;
    public MyJspFactory(JspFactory factory) {
        _myFactory = factory;
    } 
   //All abstract methods which looks up _myFactory and does the same thing

   public PageContext getPageContext(Servlet servlet, ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, String errorPageURL, boolean needsSession, int bufferSize, boolean autoflush) {
        PageContext myCtxt = _myFactory.getPageContext(....)
        //Create a customPageContext and wrap myCtxt in it and return
   }
}
```

Create a CutsomPageContext class

```
public class MyPageContext extends PageContext {
    private PageContext _ctxt = null;

    public void setPageContext(PageContext ctxt) {
        _ctxt = ctxt;
    }

    //Implement all abstract methods using _ctxt object

    @override
    public  JspWriter getOut() {
        JspWriter _out = _ctxt.getOut();

        //Wrap _out object using MyJSPWriter as mentioned in question and return back;

    }
}
```

Now during the init face of the servlets, add the following lines

```
JspFactory newFactory = new MyJspFactory(JspFactory.getDefaultFactory());
JspFactory.setDefaultFactory(newFactory);
```

I have not tried it out. But conceptually it should work. Please let us know if you could achieve what you wanted through this.

Good Luck!